# Connecting two independent tables with the third and connect results in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, union

My DB size grew to over 10GB and now I need to rethink my queries. They worked as a quick and dirty solution, but it needs a lot of optimization now. I will appreciate any help and discussion on this.

I have three tables.

1. Votes (Voter_ID, CandidateID) - Stores who voted for whom (About 8 GB in size)
2. Recommendations(Voter_ID, CandidateID) - Stores who recommended whom (About 3 GB in size)
   (Voters can both vote and recommend.)
3. Candidates(CandidateID, Election_time, Candidate_Party) (About 100 MB in size)

I need to find a lot of information from this data. The first part is to find the die hard fans of a Candidate's party. We need to get all candidates for that party and then get IDs of voters and recommenders for them.

Current query goes like this:

```
select 
Voter_ID, 
sum(votes) as vote_count,
sum(recos) as reco_count,
sum(votes) + sum(recos)) as total
 from 
((select Voter_ID, 
count(CandidateID) as votes, 0 as recos from votes,
recommendations 
where CandidateID=CandidateID 
and Candidate_Party in ('abcd') 
and Election_time >= '2013-01-01'
and Election_time <='2014-01-1' 
group by Voter_ID) 

UNION ALL 

(select 
Voter_ID, 
0 as votes, 
count(CandidateID) as recos 
from 
votes, 
recommendations 
where 
CandidateID=CandidateID and 
Candidate_Party in ('abcd') and 
Election_time >= '2013-01-01' and Election_time <='2014-01-1' 
group by Voter_ID)
) as usercount group by Voter_ID 
order by total desc
```

I wish I could format it better. But this query is very slow with my database. There is indexing in place but the data size kills my server with 3GB of RAM. I would really like to optimize this query to the fullest and then add RAM if needed. Thank you for your answer in advance.

Comment: Can you please post the exact details of your indexes and the explain plan of your query? If a VOTER_ID appears in both halves of the UNION do you want both rows or just one?

Comment: If the voter has both recommended and voted for a candidate, I only want his id once but I want to know how many candidates from a party has he liked. For instance, John liked 98 candidates from Party named ABC and he recommended 12 candidates. I will add details on indexes soon. On my way home right now.

Comment: Here are the index details: CandidateID is a BTree Index. In other two tables (Voter_ID, CandidateID) is a primary key and there is another Btree index on CandidateID.